# Wordpress homepage directing to index.html

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress site is set up to be a static wordpress page (named "home"). Recently though, the site is pointing the home page to index.html instead of the "home" page. Even when I change the home page from "home" to something like "about" it will still direct to `index.html`, also it does it when I manually type in `site.com/home` or `site.com/index.php`.

Is there a way to revert it back? I have done nothing to the site recently, it is just a static informational site and gets updated once a year. The last time it was updated was about 6 months ago.

The theme is Noteblog

Comment: provide your `.htaccess` file. may help: go to dashboard > settings > permalinks > and just click save button.

Answer (score 1):

A typical wordpress installation doesn't have an `index.html` page/file, but instead an `index.php`. `index.html` could be a file that a provider puts into the webspace as a kind of "this domain is reserved for one of our clients" message.

Check if there is also an `index.php` file in your theme directory. If yes, just delete the `index.html` - that should be the solution in this case.